# Where are Outlook's mail accounts settings stored and how to read them?

Tags: .net, outlook

If Outlook is installed on a PC, I need to read mail account settings using .NET but without using the Outlook object model.

Comment: By Outlook Object model do you mean MAPI?

Comment: can you explain why? this sounds like the start of "how to write a virus - 101"

Answer (score 2):

This [thread](http://www.techspot.com/vb/all/windows/t-8927-Outlook-2003-Accounts-File.html) includes notes on Outlook registry keys that may be useful.